# Using a middleware in Django make my path not accessible

Tags: django

I got an app, that ref to two installed app, one is `api`, another is webapp.
the webapp got a middleware.

[image]

to avoid the middleware discard my `/api` request, I use `self.get_response` to handle it, if the request path is start with `/api`.
[image]

Here is my `urls.py` in `api`
[image]

and it is my `views.py` in `api`
[image]

I call `localhost:3000/api/foo`, it returns me a 404 not found error.
I tried to update the `api/urls.py` to `api/foo`, but it is not success.

more result from the screen cap:
[image]

Comment: Do you add your app's urls to your project's urls? (`project_name/urls.py`)

Comment: @EDG956 yes, I did.

In my `<project_name>/urls.py`

I added    

`path('api/foo', include('api.urls')),`

Comment: Do you not get more info from django when running with DEBUG=True?

Comment: Ahh I think I know what happens. You added under the root url `api/foo` the subroute `foo`, so your actual path looks like `api/foo/foo`

Comment: @EDG956 I upload the info on the org post.

Comment: Did you try hitting `api/foo/foo`? although it's weird it doesn't appear in Django's list, but it's definitely a problem with routing, not middleware.